# How can I change the cursor from right to the left in jQuery menu

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem in jQuery and  I am using menu object, I took it from [here](http://jqueryui.com/menu/).

But the problem that when I want to change sub menu direction from the left to the right so I can make it in Arabic, the direction change very well! by (dir='rtl') but the menu cursor still in the right?!! ([Link with image for my problem](http://im65.gulfup.com/eL1yPZ.png)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the jQuery UI demo you provided, you can override the following classes with the properties I'm including:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon {
    left: 0;
}

.ui-icon-carat-1-e {
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
```

The above changes produce the following:

[image]